# Laravel Eloquent select data from one Model by checking another Model values

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to select all the Offers with the condition that it is not completed (data not exist on OffersProof OR offers proof status  = 0 with multiple where conditions in OffersProof)

***List offers that do not have the proof. If proof exists then check the status of it. if that is 0 then show it in the list.***

Offers Model

```
class Offers extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'offers';
    protected $fillable = [ "name","desc"];
    protected $hidden = [];
}
```

Offers Proof Model

```
class OffersProof extends Model
{

protected $table = 'offers_proof';
protected $fillable = [ "offer", "user","pub","time","status" ];
protected $hidden = []; 
}
```

Here is the query that I have tried. There are issues in the selection. Not sure this one works as perfect or needs to implement this using relation.

```
 $user = "test";
 $pub = "demo";
 $offers = Offers::leftJoin('offers_proof', function($leftJoin)use($user,$pub)
        {
              $leftJoin->on('offers_proof.offer', '=', 'offers.id');
              $leftJoin->where('offers_proof.user', '=', $user);
              $leftJoin->where('offers_proof.pub', '=', $pub); 
              $leftJoin->where('offers_proof.status', '!=', 0); 
        })->where($conditions)->get();
```

This code returns all the offers. I want to filter the offers that have no proof on the OffersProof table.

Is there any better way to take the data with good performance query and how can I select the offers as per the above requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed the DB::Raw part and one condition to check whether left join data exists.

```
$user = "test";
 $pub = "demo";
 $offers = Offers::leftJoin('offers_proof', function($leftJoin)use($user,$pub)
        {
              $leftJoin->on('offers_proof.offer', '=', 'offers.id');
              $leftJoin->where('offers_proof.user', '=', DB::raw("'$user'"));
              $leftJoin->where('offers_proof.pub', '=', DB::raw("'$pub'")); 
              $leftJoin->where('offers_proof.status', '!=', DB::raw("0")); 
        })->where('offers_proof.user', '=', NULL)->where($conditions)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select offers that are not complete OR offers proof status = 0. I think this code should work.

```
$user = "test";
$pub = "demo";
$offers = Offers::leftJoin('offers_proof', 'offer', 'offers.id')
    ->select(*)
    ->where('offers_proof.user', $user)
    ->where('offers_proof.pub', $pub)
    ->where('offers_proof.status', 0)
    ->where($conditions)
    ->get();
```

Comment: This code returns a null array. On data selection, OffersProof needs to be empty (record not exist on offersproof table). If exist then check the user,pub, and status values. If data exist with same user and pub then its status needs to be 0 else it will not be selected.